# How do I accomplish this percentage issue

Tags: javascript, math, percentage

I'm working in JavaScript. 
I have a graphic done and it is somewhat like this.

`100 [=======||=======]  200`

So basically this is a kind of mathematical problem. On the left and right side are two numbers, as a range. The 3rd number, in between this range will be defined and the || mark is moved according to this 3rd number.

So in this example the 3rd number is 150, which makes the || divider in the exact middle.
What I want is a way to calculate a percentage value from these 3 given numbers to align the || divider through a `css left: xx%` property. How might I do this?

EDIT:
I'm adding the fiddle as told by the users.
http://jsfiddle.net/e2dLv/1/

any suggestions/critics about the code are welcome.

It is solved now as answered by Zeta. It may help someone.

Comment: I'd suggest you show your actual HTML and CSS rather than just a diagram.  Even better, put it in a working jsFiddle so folks can see exactly what you're working with and show you how their answer works.

Comment: In other words, you have a range slider and you want to be able to calculate where the handle should be given a value.

Comment: Depends on what you want the 3rd number to be a percentage of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically linear scaling with an initial offset:

```
p = 100 * (value - min) / (max - min)
```

[image: plot]

Note that this assumes that `value` is in the interval `[min, max]` and `max != min`. This gives you the percentage as a number between `0` and `100`.

Comment: Zeta, I can't   believe I had written the same code but I wasn't confident enough that it is correct.

Comment: I just tried to figure out how it should work and I typed the code. After seeing your answer and then comparing, It is exactly the same.   http://i.imgur.com/9Ndg5BJ.jpg

Comment: @karan: I used [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) for the graph: `set xrange [100:200]; set yrange [0:100]; set xlabel "Original value"; set ylabel "Percentage %"; plot (x-100)/(200-100) * 100`. Btw, since you're new to the platform, you might want to have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work